# Windows XP not recognizing my 4TB WD harddrive

Tags: windows-xp, external-hard-drive

Just now got Western Digital 4TB hard drive. WD4003FZEX. I have Windows XP and I know there is no straight forward solution in XP to make use of entire 4TB. Is there any workaround in XP to make use of 4TB.

I tried to configure the disc from Windows 7 by changing my partition to GPT from windows 7 machine. But I need to use the backup drive at Win XP only and GPT is not supported by Win XP.

Note: There is a workaround from WD site that they recommend True Image software, which recognizes 4TB. I tried that and it's working. But that software has some limited functionalities and to use the full feature, I need to purchase it. The main problem is I already have a licensed True Image program which is pretty old. When trying to install this it's forcing to uninstall my licensed SW which I don't want to do, since all my previous backups were created with that version.

Comment: I remember Acronis True Image having an upgrade price too. That was several years ago, though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This demonstrates remarkable fortitude!. That said, it might be time to use a newer OS. Get the free ESXi from VMWare, or the Linux of your choice, with Virtual Box or some other end-user VM product. You can have your 4TB disk, a modern OS with modern security features and multi-media opportunities, with one or more instances of XP running on one or more VMs.

Its possible the XP environment can really use 4TB, but I suspect its more likely that multiple partitions of 2TB would do as well. An other alternative would be to partition the monster drive and integrate it into some speedy little computer that your XP machine can mount the partitions of.

Point is, keep the XP for whatever you are enjoying it with, but don't worry about getting it to understand modern hardware, after a decade+ of Moore's law. Don't spend your hard earned money on obsolete software.

And good luck!

Bill

Comment: MBR limits the disk to  2^32 sectors. With 512 byte sectors that it 2TiB. That is how much disk can be addressed, which means that multiple partitions inside that disk will not solve it.

Answer (score 4):

#### Windows XP not recognizing my 4TB WD harddrive

Windows XP does not support using all 4TB. You can use the first 2.1TB

In order to use all 4TB you need to upgrade to a newer version of Windows and have a motherboard that supports UEFI.

---

> This drive does not support older operating systems like Windows XP. You can use this drive in Windows XP or even Windows 98, but you will be limited to the first 2.1 TB.

Source [The 4 TB Western Digital Black (WD4003FZEX)](http://www.techarp.com/showarticle.aspx?artno=802&pgno=2)

---

> **Getting Around The 2.1 TB Limit**
>
> Advanced Format can also help the industry get beyond 2.1 TB capacity
>   limit, which was brought about by the LBA addressing limit in 32-bit
>   operating systems. These operating systems can only support up to 4.29
>   million sectors, which translates to 2,199,023,255,552 bytes if each
>   sector is 512 bytes.
>
> The only way to get around this is to upgrade to 48-bits Long LBA,
>   which supports up to 144 petabytes, if each sector is 512 bytes.
>   However, this solution requires the use of a newer 64-bit operating
>   system (e.g. Windows Vista, Windows 7, Mac OS X) and a motherboard
>   that supports UEFI.

Source [The New Advanced Format Drives](http://www.techarp.com/showarticle.aspx?artno=682&pgno=0)

---

#### Further reading

- [Windows support for hard disks that are larger than 2 TB](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/2581408) goes into a lot more detail on this subject.

Comment: You can use GPT hard drives as data drives on AT BIOS-based systems, but not boot for them.

Comment: `in order to use all 4TB you need to upgrade to a newer (64 bit) version of Windows`. Sorry, no. 32 bit win7 (with GPT) will work just fine. I recommend deleting the (64 bit) part.  Other than that: +1 for a good answer.

Comment: @Hennes 64 bit is required for UEFI + GPT boot volume. But I will remove the 64 bit to keep it simple.

Comment: Oh, nice info. I did not realise that part. I guess that this is because I am still booting from an old MBR disk and onlyt using GPT for data. (Old systems, setup 5+ years ago)